# Mysql query between 2 dates from multiple tables that has relation

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have trouble with my query.

I have a gridview that counts all the students who have a particular ailment according to their section. And what I want is to filter between 2 dates since I have multiple tables.

```vb
Dim query As String

query = "SELECT count(student_id) as i from students, patient, ailment 
         WHERE students.sid=patient.student_id AND 
         patient.ailment_id=ailment.ailment_id and section WHERE 
         patient.date_created BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2"

Dim data_table As New DataTable
sql_command = New MySqlCommand(query, myconnection.open())

sql_command.Parameters.Add("@d1", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
            dateStart.Value
sql_command.Parameters.Add("@d2", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
            dateEnd.Value

Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql_command)

adapter.Fill(data_table)
DataGridView1.DataSource = data_table

myconnection.close()
```

Datagrid

[image: link for datagrid sample]

Error

[image: link to query error]

Comment: there is a second `WHERE` on your query (third line of the query). You need to remove the second `WHERE` and fix the `section` condition.

Comment: Well, you have a double `WHERE` condition, did you forget a join somewhere?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I added the code to what I have tried so far but it throws error. I think it's because of multiple where clause.

Comment: @Kimmy it is exactly because of that as already mentioned. You are missing joins as well. This is a debugging issue and or a problem that can't be reproduced and more than likely will be voted to be closed out.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I am confused with my query. What could be the exact query?

Comment: @Kimmy see the answer below. But you may need to to explain this part of your query `and section` which may just be a typo. And the point about using `INNER JOIN ... ON ... = ...` is useful too.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have two time where

```
            SELECT count(student_id) as i 
            from students, patient, ailment 
            WHERE students.sid=patient.student_id 
            AND patient.ailment_id=ailment.ailment_id 
            AND patient.date_created BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2
```

Second, you have also a `and section` that is not clear (check for your real condition and eventually update your code).

Anyway you should use an explicit JOIN syntax and not old and unclear implicit version based on where:

```
SELECT count(student_id) as i 
from students
INNER JOIN patient ON students.sid=patient.student_id 
INNER JOIN ailment ON atient.ailment_id=ailment.ailment_id 
WHERE  patient.date_created BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2"
```